# Как найти несколько чисел в диапазоне двух значений Python

Tags: python

Допустим есть список с со значениями диапазона. Нужно равномерно разделить этот диапазон на несколько чисел.

Пример:

- Диапазон от 0 до 10.
- Коэффициент деления 4
- Результат = 0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10

Есть ли в python встроенные методы для решения этой задачи?

Comment: во внешней библиотеке есть [np.linspace(0, 10, 5)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)

Comment: А чем плох цикл for или конструктор списка с for?

Answer (score 1):

Простой вариант на генераторе:

```
def prange(start, stop, part):
    step = (stop-start)/part
    while True:
        yield start
        if start >= stop:
            break
        start = start + step
```

Вывод:

```
>>> list(prange(0,10,4))
[0, 2.5, 5.0, 7.5, 10.0]
>>>
```